# How to break out of a doseq?

Tags: clojure

I am relatively new to Clojure. I was trying to use `doseq` by writing a simple method `isPrime` which will return true or false.

How do I return false and break out of the `doseq` call if I find a particular number to be dividing n by remainder 0?

and how do I know I went all the way till the end of the list ?

Do I have to always go through all the elements in the list ?

Also should I use an atom as a flag to keep track of whether I found one number that divides n or not?

I am stuck at a point:

```
(defn isPrime
  #_=>  "Is the given number prime"
  #_=>  [n]
  #_=>  (doseq [i 2 (int (inc (Math/sqrt n)))]
  #_=>    (if (= (mod n i) 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a way to break out of a `doseq` by using an exception, but you really shouldn't use `doseq` in such a case. It is not designed for such problems.

The standard library function `not-any?`, on the other hand, does exactly what you need. In similar cases, you should also consider `not-any?`'s siblings, `some?`, `every?`, and `not-every?`.

Here's an example solution that correctly implements the (very naive) algorithm from your code:

```
(defn prime?
  "Returns true if n is a prime number."
  [n]
  (not-any? #(zero? (mod n %))
            (range 2 (inc (Math/sqrt n)))))
```

Comment: Thank you I was already on this track. I was using filter to get out the ones that are divisible and see the count to decide.
I didn't know about not-any!

Comment: There is no such thing as `any?`.

Comment: @tar: Sorry, that one's names `some?`. Thanks for the notification, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

doseq shouldn't be used for that purpose. You need to shift your coding style from imperative to functional.

```
(doc doseq)
Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
bindings and filtering as provided by "for". Does not retain
the head of the sequence. Returns nil.
```

doseq isn't supposed to be used like ***for*** and ***while*** constructs in Java.

Have a look at these implementations to have a feel on how to implement is-prime in Clojure: [Clojure Euler - Problem 007](http://clojure-euler.wikispaces.com/Problem+007)

Answer (score 0):

There is no break in clojure, but `doseq` and `for` behavior can be enriched by using `:let`, `:when`, and `:while` keywords.

With the `:while` keyword you can add a condition to the `doseq` loop, then use a boolean flag to make it stop. Below is an example. It reads passwords continuously until the right one is typed, then breaks the loop:

```clj
(def locked true)
(doseq [line (take-while not-empty (repeatedly read-line)) :while locked] (do
    (if (= line "2002") (do 
        (println "Access Granted")
        (def locked false)
    )
        (println "Invalid Password")
    )
))
```

You can also do early exit with the `loop` or `when` statements. Those loops which have to end with a recursive call, such as `(recur (inc i))` as they use tail recursion (just like a function would do with `defn` keyword). So, in those loops you can force a break by sending a different value to the recursive call - a value which will make it match the break condition.

The example below searches for a key in an array variable arr. The recursive call is used as a break by causing the loop to halt, when it sets i to n instead of i+1:

```clj
(loop [i 0] (when (< i n)
    (def arri (nth arr i))
    (if (= key arri) (do
        (def foundIndex i)
        (recur n)
    )
        (recur (inc i))
    )
))
```

We can also change this loop so that it handles the not-found condition as well. The example below is a bit tricky. It counts from 0 to n instead of 0 to n-1:

```clj
(loop [i 0] (when (<= i n)
    (if (= i n) (do
        (def notFound true)
        (recur (inc i))
    ) (do
        (def arri (nth arr i))
        (if (= key arri) (do
            (def foundIndex i)
            (recur n)
        )
            (recur (inc i))
        )
    ))
))
```